# Java code format String to US zip code

Tags: java, string-formatting

Could you please share a java code snippet to convert 5 or 9 digit number to US ZIP code format

```
e.g. 
Input -> Expected output
12345 -> 12345
123456789 -> 12345-6789
```

Below code works but for 5 digit it ends with -. How to remove this using regular expression?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String[] values = new String[]{"1234","12345","123456897"};

    MaskFormatter f = new MaskFormatter("#####-####");
    f.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
    for(String value:values){
        System.out.println(f.valueToString(value));
        //System.out.println(String.format("%5s-%04s", value,value));
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
234 -
12345-
12345-6897
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
 String[] values = new String[]{"1234","12345","123456897"};

    MaskFormatter f = new MaskFormatter("#####-####");
    f.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
    for(String value:values){
        String output=f.valueToString(value).trim();
        if(output.endsWith("-")){            
            output=output.substring(0,output.length()-1);
        }
        System.out.println(output);
        //System.out.println(String.format("%5s-%04s", value,value));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
1234 
12345
12345-6897
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String convertZip(String unconverted) {
    if (unconverted.length() > 5) {
        return unconverted.substring(0, 5) + "-" + unconverted.substring(5);
    }
    else {
        return unconverted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your number(any number of digit) to String and then validate the length and consider only `length = 5` and `length =9`. Then you can take value as it is if length is 5. if length is 9 use `substring()` in Java and divide your `String` `0-5` and `5-9` then add - between two part. Now it is your zip code.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two formatters and use the appropriate one based on the length of the value.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
   String[] values = new String[] { "1234", "12345", "123456897" };

   MaskFormatter f5 = new MaskFormatter("#####");
   f5.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);

   MaskFormatter f9 = new MaskFormatter("#####-####");
   f9.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);

   for (String value : values) {
      System.out.println(value.length() > 5 ? f9.valueToString(value) : f5.valueToString(value));
   }
}
```

Personally, I think I'd go in a different direction:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ParseException {
    String[] values = new String[] { "1234", "12345", "123456897" };
    for (String value : values) {
        System.out.println(value.length() > 5 ? new StringBuilder(value).insert(5, "-").toString() : value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

```
var reformat = "123456789".replace(/(\d{5})/g, function(match){
        return match + "-";
 });
console.log(reformat.replace(/\-$/, ""));
```

Comment: The original poster is asking for Java, not Javascript.